# Scrolling Banner - what is the best way to implement it?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I need to implement "banner" view in Android. Lets say that banner has 5 images, and one is visible on screen. After user press left (or right) button, the image slides from right to left. When you are on 5th image, after "next" button press you scroll to image 5.

Question is: What is the best way to implement such thing ? I've digged this https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo . It uses scroll view and Runnable with timer schedule, to scroll images.

I was also thinking about using animation class, which looks pretty easy and "clean".

I have no experience with Animation nor ScrollView, so I would like to ask about it someone more experienced.

If you have any links for tutorials/patterns/solutions presenting such a banner I would also appreciate posting them.

Answer (score 2):

One of your best bets would probably be a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) from the v4 compatibility library. This just takes a `PagerAdapter` which you can use to create a set of `ImageView`s.

The `ViewPager` will handle the animation and appropriate sliding effects for you.

Comment: I've consider your advice and found this site: [link](http://life-optimized.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-create-image-viewer-using.html) but after all, I've implemented what I needed using translation animations. Works pretty well. Cheers and thanks for advice !